# Can't Depoly laravel on digitalocean nginx

Tags: laravel, nginx, digital-ocean

So I followed [this instruction](https://gist.github.com/santoshachari/87bf77baeb45a65eb83b553aceb135a3) step by step to deploy my laravel project into digitalocean ,but instead of creating a new laravel project ,I cloned my own project from gitlab

at the end I opened my website and I got the default html page

> Please log into your droplet via SSH to configure your LEMP installation.

here is my nginx file :

```
# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/tooran/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name 162.243.39.12;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
            # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
            # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your project folder structure and is there any error display while restart your nginx server?

Comment: @KelvinKyaw it's not an error it's digitalocean default page   and it's a simple laravel project nothing special

Comment: @KelvinKyaw sorry my bad ,no ! there is no error in command line (it doesn't show any thing just goes to next line no error no success message)

Comment: @KelvinKyaw I edited the question and attached project folder structure if you meant this

Comment: :D What I mean is `/var/www/html/public_html` something like that :)

Comment: @KelvinKyaw `/var/www/tooran/public/index.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I contact digitalocean and they told me to edit `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/digitalocean` instead of `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

p.s: make sure that you have .env file in your laravel folder too

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about your example but [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-in-ubuntu-16-04) you can find great tutorial for LEMP stack. Make sure you change strings `root /var/www/html;` to `root /var/www/your_project/public;` and

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

to

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`file.

Comment: I did all of this as you see in my nginx file

Comment: Yeap, but this message `Please log into your droplet via SSH to configure your LEMP installation` looks like your LEMP installed or configured incorrect.